# Winforms soltuion starts but debugging is not available

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to debug a winforms application in Visual Studio 2013 and I am able to start the program fine. However, the pause button and stop button are both grayed out after the application has already compiled and executed. Additionally, what should be my continue buttons is now a start button.

The pause and stop are available for a split second after execution starts but then it becomes the state detailed above.

This started happening after I installed dotTrace by JetBrains, I uninstalled dotTrace thinking it would help but it left my VS in this state.

Comment: Yes, that's a pretty annoying bug in VS20`3.  The Debug menu and the shortcut keys still work.

Comment: @HansPassant The hot keys dont work unfortunately.